# How to fix 'IdentityModel.dll not found'?

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint, dll, wsp

I am trying to use IdentityModel.dll via a custom class library.

I have a Web Service (*which will be deployed in SharePoint as WSP*) where I want to use IdentityModel.Oidcclient DLL. This DLL is unsigned (does not have strong name). The signed version of DLL is asking for higher version of .Net framework. We cannot upgrade.

**To solve this issue:**
I referred the IdentityModel.dll in my custom class library MyLibrary.dll and referred custom class library MyLibrary.dll in my original project 'MyWebService'.

**Per plan**, the unsigned issue of Identitymodel.OidcClient is resolved. **But** we are getting error for IdentityModel.dll.

**Now I am getting error**

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'IdentityModel, Version=3.10.6.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e7877f4675df049f' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.":"IdentityModel, Version=3.10.6.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=e7877f4675df049f"}

.

I added the same version in project. Even public key token is same. I deployed the DLL in GAC using GACUTIL. But not resolved. I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following key to the section in your web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" >    
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="IdentityModel, Version=3.10.6.0, 
          Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e7877f4675df049f" />
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: Thanks. This may work for someone but not worked for me. I deployed the DLL in assembly using GACUTIL.